# Posição Relativa da linha da Tabela

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, css-seletores

- Tenho uma tabela com 50 linhas
- Destas somente 10 estão visíveis
- Foi adicionado o class css "ux-select" a linha 5

O código `$('table tbody tr:visible.ux-select').index()` me dirá qual o numero da linha no contexto da tabela como um todo (retornará 5)

**Pergunta:** Como faço pra pegar a posição relativa desta linha, ou seja, como a tabela só possui 10 linhas visíveis, a linha 5 que esta com o `class ux-select`, esta em que posição dentre as visíveis? (1ª? 2ª? 3ª?....nº?)

Comment: Posta o código de como esta tabela foi montada, ficaria mais fácil ajudarmos você :). Caso seja muito grande use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: A tabela é 100% dinâmica! Por isso dei um exemplo simples e bem genérico! Mais se responder baseado nele já me ajuda!

Comment: ela pode ser dinâmica, mas é gerado somente html para o navegador, você pode tentar botão direito exibir código fonte..

Comment: Editei a pergunta! veja se consegui ser mais claro agora!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lógica é +- contar os irmão anteriores que estejam visíveis.

```
var index = $('table tbody tr:visible.ux-select').prevAll(':visible').length + 1;
```

Segue um exemplo:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmosantos/ap4adtmc/2/

Comment: Isto não responde à pergunta. Quando você tiver [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficiente, você vai poder deixar [comentários em qualquer post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) mas, até lá, escreva apenas resposta que não [dependam de mais informações de quem perguntou](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/126156)

Comment: Olá, sou novo aqui mas não entendi sua colocação. A resposta que coloquei não dependia de mais informações, pois coloquei até um link de exemplo. Editei agora e coloquei o código direto na resposta.

Comment: @DiegoSantos, valeu brother! ajudou muito

Comment: Da forma que estava, não dava para entender a sua solução sem acessar o link. Ainda que a resposta esteja no link, é importante que ela esteja descrita na sua resposta para que não se perca com possíveis links quebrados.